# Animating changes to a Session variable, set in an interval in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have Meteor.setInterval find one recent item in my collection and then sets it in a session every 1 seconds.

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
  var entries = Database.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });
  Session.set('entryName', entries); 
}, 1200);
```

I need this as it only gets the most recent entry and prevents flooding of other entries as it fires only once a second. Is there anyway of animating this (lets say add a fade effect)? Its a problem because if I animate to the interval, it will fade in and out every second, even if a new entry hasn't been added.

I need it to fade only if the entry changes. Is there maybe a better way of rewriting the code in a Meteor way so its easier to animate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I did, pretty funny way of doing it:

```
Database.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 1}).observeChanges({
  addedBefore: function(id, fields) {
      var isItOn = true
      Session.set('isItTrue', isItOn);     
  }
});
```

Then underneath:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
  var isItOn = Session.get('isItTrue');
    if (isItOn === true) {

// Place Animation Here

   var entries = Database.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });      
   Session.set('entryName', entries);
   var isItOn = false;   
   Session.set('isItTrue', isItOn);
  }
}, 1200);
```

Also note, I received an error when I used 'added', had to use 'addedBefore'.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you will want to use `observeChanges` here instead of a timer. Meteor already monitors for changes to your collection and will fire a `observeChanges` event when that happens. This might be what you want:

```js
var throttled = _.throttle(function(){
  Session.set('entryName', fields);
  // do your animations here
},1000);

Database.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 1}).observeChanges({
  added: function(id, fields) { throttled() };
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Christian I'll give it a try, the only issue is i'm not sure if it takes into account of flooding. The database is going to be updated rapidly by many users so I need it to only show a entry every so and so seconds. Ill try add an interval to the session.get maybe

Comment: @LisaS I added a `_.throttle()` to limit the update rate.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I did it a funny way earlier today which worked. Not sure which one is more efficient. I put a variable that would be set to 'true' every time a change is observed (inside .observeChanges) and put it in a session.set.

Next I made a session.get to retrieve the truthy in the Meteor.setInterval. I put it in a if statement with the Database.findOne() 

I'll write it down below

Comment: @MichelFloyd Actually I gave the throttle method a try and it didn't work

Comment: How did it not work? Did it not set the variable or did it not slow down the setting?

Comment: @MichelFloyd nothing inside _.throttle gets set off, observeChanges works fine

Comment: It really should work! [Docs](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) say it should fire immediately on first invocation then no more than every `wait` milliseconds after that.

Comment: @MichelFloyd also thinking about it, even if the throttle did work the code looks wrong. It looks like the animation will fire every time a change is observed.. the throttle will just slow down the next entry from being shown (set in a session). So if I did a fade effect, it will just keep fading in and out no matter if its a new entry or not..

Comment: @MichelFloyd I think I had trouble with the _.throttle months ago with a similar question. Doesn't want to fire in strange places

Comment: ok, figured it out. See revised code. `_.throttle()` creates a new _function_. You still need to invoke it.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Something on the "added: function(id, fields) { throttled() };" line is causing the app to crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112642/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-lisa-s).